# How to scrape multiple pages using selenium where next page data is loaded with js _doPostBack() I need to loop through all pages

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, dopostback

```
        for i in range(2,12):
            try:
                # q = '//* [@id="Content"]/tbody/tr[18]/td/table/tbody/tr/td['+str(i)+']'
                # continue_link = browser.find_element_by_xpath(q).click()
                q = str(i)
                continue_link = browser.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Page$'+q).click()
```

Iam able to use commented lines but there is limitation when it come to 11(I am getting struck with "..."symbol) 9 10 ...
So instead of that I choose to use href but next page is loading using JS _doPostBack method. I need to select go through each page until end page.  Please help.

Comment: will it be possible for you to share the app URL?

Comment: sorry @MaranSowthri I wish I could have that freedom, here I can't.